# Recursion angular directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to use recursion in angular directives.

Follow the code with the template without recursion.

It is a left menu that must be created recursively.

I'm not sure how to put the recursion.

I tried `'<leftmenu menuLeft = "itemmenu"> </ leftmenu>'`, but so only the profile image appears several times.

```
.directive('leftmenu', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
retrict: 'E',
scope: { menuLeft: '=?' },
template: '<div class="user-panel">' +
                '<div class= "pull-left image">' +
                    '<img src="{{ menuLeft.profileImgSrc }}" class="img-circle" alt="{{ menuLeft.profileName  }}" />' + 
                '</div>' + 
                '<div class="pull-left info">' + 
                    '<p>{{ menuLeft.profileName }}</p>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' + 
            '<ul class="sidebar-menu">' +
                '<li class="header">{{ menuLeft.header }}</li>' +
                '<li class="treeview" ng-repeat="itemmenu in menuLeft.itens">' +
                    '<a href="{{ itemmenu.actionLink }}">' +
                        '<i class="{{ itemmenu.visualClass }}"></i> <span>{{ itemmenu.label }}</span>' +
                        '<span class="pull-right-container" ng-show="{{ itemmenu.subItems.length > 0 }}">' +
                            '<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>' +
                        '</span>' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '<ul class="treeview-menu">' +
                        '<li ng-repeat="subItem in itemmenu.subItems">' +
                            '<a ng-if="subItem.openInNewWindow" target="_blank" href="{{ subItem.actionLink }}">' +
                                '<i {{ subItem.class }}></i>{{ subItem.label }}' +
                            '</a>' +
                            '<a ng-if="!subItem.openInNewWindow" target="_self" href="{{ subItem.actionLink }}">' +
                                '<i {{ subItem.class }}></i>{{ subItem.label }}' +
                            '</a>' +
                        '</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>',

compile: function (element) {

},

controller: function ($location, $http, $scope) {

                $scope.menuLeft = {
                    "profileName": "",
                    "profileImgSrc": response.data.msgSaida[0].profileImgSrc,
                    "header": "",
                    "itens": response.data.msgSaida[0].itens,
                    "token": token
                };
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

};

Comment: It may be just me, but I am not able to understand your requirement . Can you add some use case and a sample wireframe(boxes drawn from Microsoft paint would also do) to understand it

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, if you're still looking to resolve this with a recursive directive, it depends what your data structure looks like, but assuming from what you've posted it looks like this:

```
{
    "profileName": "",
    ...
    "items": [{
        "label": "title1",
        "class": "class1",
        "items: [...]
    },{
        "label": "title1",
        "class": "class1",
        "items: [...]
    }]
}
```

You can split them into two directives:

- One is the parent sidePanel directive that contains the top level
- One is the menuList directive that will recursively display sub items

```
// profile image
// profile name
// etc
<menu-list items="leftMenu.items"></menu-list>
```

where menu list template was like:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">
       <span class="{{item.class}}">{{item.label}}</span>
       <menu-list ng-if="item.items" items="item.items"></menu-list>
   </li>
</ul>
```

So in each instance of a menu object (label,class,items) the items will be converted into a sub menu-list.  You might need to play with it a little and add in some other features.